# Question about defining cuts?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question from Analysis Text. Not sure how to approach this…

> A multiplicative inverse of a nonzero cut $x=A\mid B$ is a cut $y=C\mid D$, such that $x \times y =1$.
>   If $x<0$, what are $C$ and $D$?

I have that we would define $y$ as $y = −(−x)^{−1}$, but I don't know how to get $C$ and $D$ from that.

Answer (score -1):

Let $$ C=\{\,c\in\mathbb Q\mid \forall a\in A\colon ac\ge1\,\}$$
and
$$ D=\mathbb Q\setminus C.$$
Chek if this also works for rational cuts.